# Display clickable list items based on condition in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Let's say I have this list of people I want to display. Below you'll see the HTML for this iteration in a `*ngFor` loop. You can view [this StackBlitz](https://angular-kdcwhd.stackblitz.io) to check out the full example.

```html
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of names" role="listitem">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
    <h4 mat-line>{{name.firstName}}</h4>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

*In some cases* the list should be displayed as a linked list, since the list of people then link to other webpages. What I could do to achieve this is to write an `*ngIf` that checks if it should be a linked list or a normal list, as written below.

```html
<div *ngIf="isNormalList; else isLinkedList">
  <h3>Normal list with items</h3>
  <mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of names" role="listitem">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
      <h4 mat-line>{{name.firstName}}</h4>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</div>

<ng-template #isLinkedList>
  <h3>List with clickable items</h3>
  <mat-list role="list">
    <a mat-list-item href="#" *ngFor="let name of names" role="listitem">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
      <h4 mat-line>{{name.firstName}}</h4>
    </a>
  </mat-list>
</ng-template>
```

However, solving it this way seems like a lot of duplicate code. I could also write an `*ngIf` for the inner part of the list item, but that is more or less the same and ends up in duplicate code as well.

Is there a way to only add the `a` element conditionally within this setup?

Comment: You could always display the same list but when you don't want the items to be clickable just remove the click event from the `a` element and it's styling.

Comment: @PaulCosma Thanks, I considered that, but I don't want to have the `a` element rendered at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. I think you can ease the `context` bit when using `$implicit` to make it shorter, but not sure how exactly, you can check the Angular docs.

On a side note, I don't think you need to specify the `role` attributes, Material should provide these for you.

```
<div>
  <mat-list role="list">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isNormalList; else isLinkedList">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of names" role="listitem">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listItem; context: { $implicit: name }"></ng-container>
      </mat-list-item>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #isLinkedList>
      <a mat-list-item href="#" *ngFor="let name of names" role="listitem">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listItem; context: { $implicit: name }"></ng-container>
      </a>
    </ng-template>

  </mat-list>
</div>

<ng-template #listItem let-name>
  <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
  <h4 mat-line>{{name.firstName}}</h4>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Although it may look like more code, I think this is the best way to do it in an Angular way. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is balance to be found here between saving lines and remaining readable, I think it could get over complicated trying to ensure absolutely no code repetitions.

Simple and readable.

```
<div>
  <h3>List with clickable items</h3>
  <mat-list role="list">
    <div *ngFor="let name of names">
      <a *ngIf="name.link" mat-list-item href="#" role="listitem">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
        <h4 mat-line>{{name.firstName}}</h4>
      </a>
      <div *ngIf="!name.link">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
        <h4 mat-line>{{name.firstName}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-list>
</div>
```

This will make the following repeated, with the addition of two new `<div>` tags.

```
<mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
<h4 mat-line>{{name.firstName}}</h4>
```

Which would be the least repetitive way I could think of, without doing something weird / hacky like stretching the `<a>` over `mat-icon` and `h4` with CSS if it exists. Which isn't pleasant or particularly readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree it should be readable, but it feels like there's something Angular related missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `*ngFor` on an `ng-template` tag:

```
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="items" let-item>
    <div *ngIf="!item.link" class="card">
        <h4>Card Info:</h4>
        <p>ID: {{ item.id }}</p>
        <p>
        Title: {{ item.title }}
        </p>
    </div>
    <a *ngIf="item.link" href="{{ item.link }}" class="card">
        <h4>Card Info:</h4>
        <p>ID: {{ item.id }}</p>
        <p>
        Title: {{ item.title }}
        </p>
    </a>
</ng-template>
```

[Check out this Stackblitz for an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-example-1).

Comment: As you can read and as said in my question, you’re still writing repetitive code a lot.

Comment: Well you have to have some repetitive code if you don't want to render the `a` tag at all. This way at least uses only one `*ngFor` instead of two. But if you don't want to render the `a` tag if there is no link, you have to do it this way.